# prove the existence of a measure $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces and $F : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map from $X$ onto $Y$. If $\nu$ is a finite measure on the Borel sets of $Y$, prove that there exists a measure $\mu$ on the Borel sets of $X$ such that

$$
\int_{Y} f d\nu = \int_{X}f \circ F d \mu
$$
for all $f$ that are continuous on $Y$.

---

This is pretty hard to show the existstence of $\mu$ for me (Even for my TA). Currently I am in the chapter of Riesz Representation. Can anybody give me some hints?

Comment: It seems that one need to define $\mu(A) = \nu(F(A))$ for all Borel set $A$.

Comment: Dear John, you means that problem misses the condition $\mu(A) = \nu(F(A))$ ?

Comment: I mean can you define $\mu $ that way and show that it is a Borel measure on $X$ and that the equation in your question holds?

Comment: I think I can, then by change of variable in integral it will hold equality. Right?

Comment: I am not completely sure, is $F(A)$ still a Borel set in $Y$? And it is not clear how $F$ is onto is used.

Comment: $F(A)$ is still a Borel set in $Y$. I will think more. Thanks for a hint John!

Comment: I just come up with a proof. The idea is that the map $F^* :C(Y) \to C(X)$ is injective. Do you want the whole proof?

Comment: Is $F^*$ a dual space of $F$? Can you write your proof? I appreciate you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the fact that $F:X\to Y$ is onto, the map

$$F^* : C(Y) \to C(X),\ \ \ F^*f(x) := f(F(x))$$

is injective. Thus one can consider $C(Y)$ as a subspace of $C(X)$. By Hahn Banach theorem, the functional $f \mapsto \int_Y f d\nu$ on $C(Y)$ extends to a functional $L$ on $C(X)$. By Riesz representation, there is a Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that

$$L(f) = \int_X f d\mu , $$

Then

$$\int_Y fd\nu = L(F^*f) = \int_X f\circ F d\mu\ .$$

Comment: Could you explain what is $F^*$ and $C(X)$? I didn't not learn Banach space yet, so not familiar with such notations.

Comment: $C(X)$ is the space of continuous function

Comment: What is the Riesz representation you learnt?

Comment: For $C(X)$, I asked for making clear, however, I never saw $F^*$. The Riesz representation I've learned was for bounded and positive linear functional $L$ on $C(X)$ and for $f \in C(X)$, there exists a $\mu$ such that $L(f) = \int fd\mu$.

Comment: Good, I need to know that as there is another Riesz representation in Hilbert space theory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof that relies on facts about the topological structure of the compact metrizable space P(X) of all (Borel) probability measures on X, mentioned in the following related thread:

[Does the pushforward operator (on measures) preserve surjectiveness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998168/does-the-pushforward-operator-on-measures-preserve-surjectiveness)

The proof is this. Let $F_*: P(X) \to P(Y)$ be the pushforward operator. We want to show that $F_*$ is onto. Since the original map $F$ is onto, each Dirac delta measure $\delta_y$ on $Y$ is in the image $F_*(P(X))$. Since $F_*$ is an affine map, each finite convex combination of Diract delta measures on $Y$ is also in the image. Such combinations form a dense subset of $P(Y)$. Since $P(X)$ is compact, the image must also be compact and hence closed. So the image must be the whole set $P(Y)$.