# Does the pushforward operator (on measures) preserve surjectiveness?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $I = [0,1]$ be the unit interval. Let $\pi: I \to I$ be a Borel-measurable surjective map. Is the pushforward operator $\pi_*: \mathcal P(I) \to \mathcal P(I)$ surjective as well, where $\mathcal P(I)$ is the collection of Borel probability measures on $I$? In other words, given a probability measure $\nu \in P(I)$, does there exist a probability measure $\mu \in P(I)$ whose pushforward measure is $\nu$?

[A related thread which deals with the continuous case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593821/prove-the-existence-of-a-measure-mu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the question to MO:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196605/does-a-surjective-measurable-map-induce-a-surjective-pushforward-operator

and the answer there refers to a book in which the proof is done by relying on a uniformization result in the obvious way. To be a bit more specific, it uses the existence of a universally measurable right-inverse of $\pi$.