# Show that there exists a measure $\mu$ such that $\int_Y fd\nu=\int_Xf \circ F d\mu$ for all continuous $f$ on $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $X,Y$ are compact spaces, $F: X \to Y$ is a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$. Let $\nu$ be a finite measure on Borel sets of $Y$. Show that there exists a measure $\mu$ on Borel sets of $X$ such that $\int_Y fd\nu=\int_Xf \circ F d\mu$  for all continuous $f$ on $Y$.

I understand that I can use the surjectivity of $F$ to induce a map from $\phi$ from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$ defined by $g \to g \circ F$ and then Hahn Banach Theorem as done here: [prove the existence of a measure $\mu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593821/prove-the-existence-of-a-measure-mu)

But I don't want to do this way. For any compact $E$, define $\mu(E)=\nu(F(E))$ (Note that $F(E)$ is compact as $F$ is continuous). Then For any $E \in \mathcal{B}_X$, define $$\mu(E)=\sup_K\{\nu(F(K)): K \subset E \text{ is compact}\}$$
I want to show that $\mu$ is a measure. Suppose that it is a measure. Then we want to show if the equality holds or not. For any $E \in \mathcal{B}_Y, \mu(F^{-1}(E))=\sup_K\{\nu(F(K)):K \subset F^{-1}(E)\text{ is compact}\}=\nu(F(F^{-1}(E))=\nu(E)$ ,where the second equality holds since $\nu$ is a Regular measure and the third as $F$ is onto. Thus $$\nu(E)=\int_Y \chi_E d\nu=\int_X \chi_E \circ F d\mu=\int\chi_{F^{-1}(E)} d\mu=\mu(F^{-1}(E))$$

Thus, the equality holds for all simple functions. Now for any continuous $f$ on $Y$, $f$ is bounded and by writing $f$ as $f^{+}-f^{-}$, we can assume $f$ to be positive. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{\phi_n\}$ such that $\{\phi_n\}$ increases (uniformly) to $f$. Then $$\int_Yfd\nu=\lim_n\int_Y\phi_nd\nu=\lim_n\int_X\phi_n \circ F d\mu=\int_Xf \circ F d\mu$$

The only thing which remains to be shown is that $\mu$ as defined is a measure which I am unable to show. How can I show that, if the way $\mu$ is defined makes sense?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: This won't give a measure. Try to prove additivity (even finite additivity) to see what goes wrong. Try to picture what happens if you take $X = [0,1] \times [0,1]$, $Y=[0,1]$ and $F$ the projection on one of the factors. I think your construction might yield an outer measure, but the measurable sets of this outer measure will not be the Borel algebra of $X$ in general.

Comment: What if the support of $\nu$ is disjoint from the image of $F$?